# Setting chapter for header line for one page

Tags: header-footer, chapters

I am using the `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` with the current chaptername in the header. There is one chapter that should not appear in the table of contents, which is the reason why I'm using `\chapter*{MyChapter}`. The problem is that the chaptername of MyChapter is not shown in the header, but the name of the previous chapter.
How can I change the chaptername in the header for only one single page?

Thank you

Comment: Try `\chaptermark{MyChapter}` right after the `\chapter*`.

Comment: \markboth{title wombat}{title wombat}

Comment: @Johannes_B this worked like a charm, thanks

Answer (score 1):

With a **KOMA-Script class** you could set class option

```
headings=optiontoheadandtoc
```

Then you can use

```
\addchap[tocentry={}]{Chapter without tocentry}
```

to get an unnumbered chapter with with the same entry in header but without an entry in the table of contents.

Example:

```
\documentclass[
  headings=optiontoheadandtoc
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum
\addchap[tocentry={}]{Chapter without tocentry}
\lipsum
\chapter[Entry in header und ToC]{Another chapter}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```